# $N$ balls and $M$ boxes, probability of last $ i$ boxes are empty, non uniform probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Following my previous question about $M$ boxes and $N$ balls. Balls are thrown to the boxes at random. I have further question, when the probability is not uniform ($1/M$). i.e. probability of throwing the balls to box 1,2,..., $M$ are $p_1$ , $p_2$,..., $p_M$, respectively. What is the probability of last $i$ slots are empty, $i = 1, 2, 3, ...,M-1$?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want the probability of *any* $i$ slots being empty, regardless of their position, or specifically of the *last* $i$ slots being empty

Comment: I mean last i slots. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The probability of box $i$ being empty if you throw one ball is trivial, it is $1-p_i$. For more balls, the ball throws are independent, so just multiply the probabilities to get $$P(\text{box }i\text{ is empty after }N\text{ balls})=(1-p_i)^N$$

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to specifically the last boxes (as predetermined before the throw) being empty. The probability that the last $i$ boxes (i.e. $M-i+1, \ldots, M$) is equal to the probability that all the balls end up in the first $M - i$ boxes. The probability of that happening for each throw is $\sum_{j=1}^{M-i} p_j$, and since the throws are independent, the total probability is $(\sum_{j=1}^{M-i} p_j)^N$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Last 1 box empty is $(1-p_M)^N,$ last 2 boxes empty is $(1-p_M-p_{M-1})^N,$ and so on. The probability for last $i$ boxes empty would be $(1-p_M-\cdots -p_{M-I+1})^N$ if I got the indexing right.